# Swift 3 set global variable value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I'm trying to get some data when the view controller is loaded and set it so I can use it later in the code, but the value doesn't update. `CountData` value should be `3` at the bottom of the code but it isn't

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class FooController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var CountData

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad();

        Alamofire.request("http://foo:8080/joke.php").responseJSON{ response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: String] {

            }
            //!!SET DATA HERE!!
            self.CountData = 3
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         //!!USE IT HERE!!
          return CountData;
}
```

Comment: self.CountData = 3 after this line reload tableview again

Answer (score 0):

As Alamofire request is asynchronous you will need to call reloadData for your table.

For now, you can initialize your

```
 var CountData = 3
```

and when you get the response set the CountData you want and then call

```
 self.CountData = 5    
 yourTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: surely better not to hard code the count?  Set the count when you know how much data has been returned, and then reload the tableView